# Find percentage of company without industries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables company_industries and company(please see table info below). I need to find the percentage of companies that aren't tied to an industry. I am stuck at the division portion. here is what I have so far

```
Company(tbl1) has the following fields:

company_id
company_name
company_typ

Company industries(tbl2) has the following fields:

company_id
industry_id
company_industry_id
```

My code:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(c.company_id) / Count(ci.*)
FROM company c
LEFT JOIN company_industries ci
on c.company_id = ci.company_id
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Use `count(*) - count(cl.company_id) * 1.0` as numerstor. Assumes each company has a single industry.

Answer (score 0):

For the numerator, you need to find the count of records for which a record exists in the company_industries table using a case statement as follows

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN ci.company_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) 
FROM company c 
LEFT JOIN company_industries ci 
  ON c.company_id = ci.company_id
```

Comment: how do I get the denominator? or does this code take care of both?

Comment: It takes care of both. I didn't mention it since it's a straight count(*).